# See the invisible

Tags: riddle, rhyme, lateral-thinking, knowledge

<sub>You need to know some computer stuff (I am intentionally broad) to solve this one.</sub>

> Were you a mod, you would see my dead peer;
>   
>   The opposite tree I try to make clear.
>   When you read between lines, the answer is near;
>   If you don't, I am hidden forever, I fear.

**Who am I?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’m not sure about posting this as an answer, since you are clearly

> a (HTML) comment.

If I were a mod,

> I could see deleted comments on SE

The opposite tree refers to

> the [DOM tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) (letters of ”mod” reversed), which contains the document’s structure. A comment’s job is often to make that structure easier to understand.

When I read between the lines

> of the source code to this puzzle, I notice that there is actually a html comment between lines 1 and 2,

Which is, of course hidden, (or invisible as the title suggests) unless I do exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

May be i am over thinking, But this also fits.

You are a

> Network

Were you a mod, you would see my dead peer;

> mod can be modem. So if i were a modem, i could see the dead [peer](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/p/peer.htm)(dead device) in you (Using Dead peer detection)

The opposite tree I try to make clear.

> This can be **[EERT](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6614786/?reload=true)**[Energy Efficient Reliable Transport]. EERT is a proposed method for better data delivery ratio in network communication. So "I try to make clear" is making sense here.

Last two lines.

> I think those are just to tell to concentrate on the lines(first two) to get the correct answer. Otherwise nobody would be able to find the answer.